# How to get content of a page of a .docx file using Apache Poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I'm trying to read .docx files with styling information using Apache Poi which I have done by looping through each XWPFParagraph and working with all the XWPFRun run inside the paragraphs. Now I want to get contents of each pages. So is there a way to get the contents of each pages or is it possible to know in which page a paragraph is currently in?

This is a function that takes the absolute path of a docx file and returns an array of strings

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(absolutePath);

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        List<IBodyElement> bodyElements = document.getBodyElements();

        List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();

        /*  I want to add some kind of outer loop here for each page
            and at the end of that loop I want to add a "<hr/>" tag in the textList
        */
        for (IBodyElement bodyElement : bodyElements) {                 // Looping through paragraphs
           if (bodyElement.getElementType() == BodyElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
                XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph) bodyElement;
                
                String textToAdd = parseParagraph(paragraph); //custom funtion to handle paragraphs


                textList.add(textToAdd);

            } 
        }
        document.close();
        return textList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

As you can see my goal here is to add a `<hr/>` tag after each page. So, if somehow I can get the page number of a paragraph or loop through pages, I will be able to do that. 
Please kindly mention if you know about any other approach that may help.

Comment: Ask Word to render the Document to a PDF, then query the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

To get Page Count from `XWPFDocument` (for your outer loop), you can do something like this:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(POIXMLDocument.openPackage(YOUR_FILE_PATH));

int numOfPages = docx.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();
```

For your paragraph text,

```
for (XWPFParagraph p : document.getParagraphs()) {
    System.out.println(p.getParagraphText()); // YOUR PARAGRAPH TEXT
}
```

Comment: Thanks but My goal here is to know where there is a page break. My parseParagraph method already does the paragraph text reading part. I need to add a <hr/> tag at the end of each page for that I need to know where the page end is.(Or a page start both would do) Page count Wont help me here.